# GPRS Based OTA to the NODEMCU

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, firmware, software

I need the OTA firmware update. I have the only option in my hand GSM(GPRS SIM800), with the help of this is it possible OTA, plz help me for this how I Do OTA via GPRS, FYI, I completed OTA Via WIFI.

Answer (score 1):

Download the bin file over GPRS and then use the Update singleton object. It is declared in [Update.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/Updater.h). Example is ArduinoOTAClass::_runUpdate() in [ArduinoOTA.cpp](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ArduinoOTA/ArduinoOTA.cpp) or ESP8266HTTPUpdate::runUpdate() in [ESP8266httpUpdate.cpp](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266httpUpdate/src/ESP8266httpUpdate.cpp)